# App crashing if I hide a few controls when a page loads without using MessageDialog

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have an app in which I have a setting which allows the user to stop the app's access to their location. This is stored in Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["location"]. If the location service + this setting allows access then I load a page with the map open. If the setting allows access and the location services are Off a message is displayed and I hide a few controls when the page loads. If the setting is off then I just want to hide the controls without any message.

```
protected  override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

         .....
        // MUST ENABLE THE LOCATION CAPABILITY!!!
          var locator = new Geolocator();
          locator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;
          locator.ReportInterval = (uint)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15).TotalMilliseconds;
          setloc(locator);
          this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    }

    public async void setloc(Geolocator locator)
    {
        if (locator.LocationStatus != PositionStatus.Disabled && (bool)Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["location"]==true)
        {
            var position = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
            await MyMap.TrySetViewAsync(position.Coordinate.Point, 16D);
            ....
            return;
        }
        else if (locator.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Disabled && (bool)Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["location"] == true)
        {

            MessageDialog msgbox = new MessageDialog("Location Services are turned off. Please turn them on to save Location while saving a Tip", "Location Unavailable");
            await msgbox.ShowAsync();
            savebutton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            myMapBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            return;

        }
       ***// MessageDialog msgbox1 = new MessageDialog("Location Services are turned off. Please turn them on to save Location while saving a Tip", "Location Unavailable");
       // await msgbox1.ShowAsync();***

       savebutton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
       myMapBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    }
```

Everything is fine when that setting is on(true) but when it's off(false), something strange happens.
The code above doesn't work. It causes the app to crash but when I uncomment the part which is within *** in the code, the message is displayed and the page is loaded properly. If I just try to hide the myMapBlock and the savebutton without using the MessageDialog, it crashes.
I want to hide the controls without using the MessageDialog. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change following line:

```
setloc(locator);
```

to:

```
await Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () => { await setloc(locator); });
```

(change signature of void setloc method to Task)

In my opinion it looks like page is not loaded yet, `MessageDialog` can not be displayed. Dispatcher.RunAsync should enqueue this action and it should be proccessed after correct page initialization.

Also the base .OnNavigatedTo(..) call should be made before your location-messagedialog code.

That's my guess - can you provide a crash stacktrace?

Comment: It worked. Thanks. You forgot to mark the lambda expression async. The correct code is-.`await Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () => { await setloc(locator); });`

Comment: @NikhilGupta fixed - I 've just wrote that code "by memory" ;-)